# I need javax.microedition.io in android, what can I do ?

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

How can I get that API into our Android project.

Comment: I need to import that Library Into our Android project for Webservices Login By suing Ksoap2. I am connecting SAP SOAP web-services with Android program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding the you have a code written on J2ME platform where you are using  `javax.microedition.io`

But as you are making an application in Android and Android does not have the package available, so you need to use any library to achieve your goal.

Here is a open source library for parsing Ksoap2 data

**http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/**

Again you can use the following tutorial to get started

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data

Comment: Thanks for Your Reply My need is I Have SAP SOAP Webservices .I Want Connect to Through Android Progarm. I am Using The fallowing Code.

Comment: String username="*****";
       String pass="*****";
       
       // Create SOAP request
       
       
       SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
       
       SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
         SoapEnvelope.VER11);
       envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
       
         HttpTransportBasicAuth aht = new  HttpTransportBasicAuth(URL, username , pass); 
       
       //HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

Comment: ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

       // Get response from envelope
       Object result = envelope.getResponse();

       // Display result
       Toast.makeText(AndroidWithSapActivity.this, result.toString(),
         50000).show();

Comment: Through this i canot connect to the webservices i am getting the exception 02-09 12:05:53.552: E/AndroidRuntime(809): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.microedition.io.Connector

Comment: As per my answer I have told you that that package is not available..U need to use any library for the parsing.

Comment: Thanks for Spending Time to me